# React+Typescript как правильно cделать async запрос?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Хочу сделать компонент, который перед загрузкой берет данные с  https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=10
и записывает их в таблицу.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class About extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { data: [] };
    }
    async componentDidMount() {
        const response = await fetch(`https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=10`);
        const json = await response.json();
        this.setState({ data: json });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                {this.state.data.map(el => (
                    <li key={el.id}>
                        {el.name}: {el.price_usd}
                    </li>
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default About;
```

На чистом react всё работает, но если я использую React + TypeScript выдаёт ошибку.

UPD: Вариант на ts (который у меня не работает)

```
interface IHttpResponse<T> extends Response {
  parsedBody?: T;
}
export const http = <T>(request: RequestInfo): Promise<IHttpResponse<T>> => {
  let response: IHttpResponse<T>;
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    fetch(request)
      .then(res => {
        response = res;
        return res.json();
      })
      .then(body => {
        response.parsedBody = body;
        resolve(response);
      });
  });
};

// example consuming code
interface ITodo {
  userId: number;
  id: number;
  title: string;
  completed: boolean;
}

const response = await http<ITodo[]>(
  "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos"
);
```

Comment: какую ошибку выдает?

Comment: @Grundy там где this.state.data.map - "TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}>' " и там где super() TS2554: Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 0. Пыталась добавить отсюда https://www.carlrippon.com/fetch-with-async-await-and-typescript/, тоже не работает

Comment: приведенный пример это на "чистом" реакте? Добавь вариант на тайпскрипте

Comment: @Grundy добавила вариант на ts. Первый пример на чистом реакте

Comment: что-то не то добавила: в первом примере у тебя компонент, во втором просто функция для запроса

Comment: @Grundy В моём компоненте вроде и должна быть одна функция для запроса. А рендер списка будет такой же так и в 1 примере показан -  в <li>

Comment: Покажи как ты ее используешь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1)

используйте интерфейсы:

```
class About extends Component<{}, {}> {}
class About extends Component<any, any> {}
```

или

```
class About extends Component<PropsI, StateI> {}
```

### 2)

пишите на JS:

```
class User {
   name = 'userName'
}
```

### 3)

и всё будет работать

[ТАМ на TS](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?alwaysStrict=false&jsx=2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AoUSWRYmAEQHkBZObXAo9GAWgBNcZcsJgBPMEjhEAzmAAacALxwA3uTga4AImB8tALjgoAdqIA06zVuMoQSA0dMXN26aJAAjCABsHJ85YaWlAmANZ+ToHaYFDAaEgA+gCu0nqG-s5WMXGJHjBoEQEuWgBMACwAFgkAbj5JdsmphZlBIChQoUgwCWgoYI1pjkVWKNUowN4oHt6J0klgYN6izVFaMBAwKN4JcwtLK8VtAB4784vL6ZHFElDxxt1oFSYA5okAjBUHWUi3SPc9T2MrwS5U+l2GQRudwegOBAHZBhlVpNpN15nwUDAkIjIgBfYTAe4-TDoSQABRwYGkAElVHB8YSsVASfE4ABlTZY2lqFwYzaGGTyADaAF0KPjyGgUdI4ABBLxJeBII5Y4x8GXIbgAOgAwrhIMY-jAADwUiBU6lmdmcpDUgB8qmELlRmKQHNdtOUKjgfJQhlF9KdmhQbmMaDgaH1EEN93oumYECS9wAFABKR0uFyR4yoqRIWTR6SSZQoADu4ywXUeyYABhUYDAqfoAPTNvrALWRwltDpVvqd3DN6pvZswOKdKDNgD83lAwBgijeAAYa6mKJnNNncwAraTRpRGcvzvMFnNILW76Np9cbuAwCrAaRaoswd1Y5Pe32GS-GelrqISi4RBqj8aYZreRAwEkUC-smUS3nAxp8MA1QRtKABythIIoWiygsWh2vBCGaCo96Ps+Npar6WptGAyZIN4SgOnBxGsYhs5wJ0oiKCoDFarouKEWxwmqHxNh2Lihi8d4WrZPEAz4iJt7Gs2s5CUpcCpqmilsSpyHVOpG7-i4+ISpqGBMMwWrAXwoHmTAnZcFiACiMx2Cm8qJjAVrGEk3jeKmVoCGg9RGlqXh8KI-6tnAyrUPAtkkn58CeYqQA)

```js
// import React from 'react';
// import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
class About extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super(...arguments);
        this.state = { data: [] };
    }
    async componentDidMount() {
        const response = await fetch(`https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=10`);
        const json = await response.json();
        this.setState({ data: json });
    }
    render() {
        return (React.createElement("div", { className: "App" }, this.state.data.map(el => (React.createElement("li", { key: el.id },
            el.name,
            ": ",
            el.price_usd)))));
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(About, null), document.body);
// export default About
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

### 4) чё-т ссылка крашится, продублирую TS код

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


type respX = {
    "id": any,
    "name": any,
    "symbol": any,
    "rank": any,
    "price_usd": any,
    "price_btc": any,
    "24h_volume_usd": any,
    "market_cap_usd": any,
    "available_supply": any,
    "total_supply": any,
    "max_supply": any,
    "percent_change_1h": any,
    "percent_change_24h": any,
    "percent_change_7d": any,
    "last_updated": any,
}

interface PropsI { }
interface StateI {
    data: respX[];
}

class About extends React.Component<PropsI, StateI> {

    state:StateI = { data: [] }

    async componentDidMount() {
        const response = await fetch(`https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=10`);
        const json = await response.json();
        this.setState({ data: json });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                {this.state.data.map(el => (
                    <li key={el.id}>
                        {el.name}: {el.price_usd}
                    </li>
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(About, null), document.body);
// export default About
```

Comment: 4) выдаёт 2 ошибки TS2304: Cannot find name 'stateStateI'. и TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null

Comment: Конечно же state:StateI